# Dependency Resolution when using multiple configurations Objects in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

We are modifying our web application to use Spring Boot (embedded tomcat). We are trying to use multiple configuration objects when starting the spring application (`SpringApplication.run(new Object[]{ConfigClass1, ConfigClass2..}, args`) which were based on XML configurations earlier. The config classes have inter dependencies configured to work with `@Autowired` on the properties. But some of the dependencies are not being injected when creating the bean. For e.g.

```
SpringApplication.run(new Object[]{ClassB.class, ClassA.class}, args);
```

---

```
@Configuration
class ClassA {

    @Autowired
    private B1D1 b1Dependency;

    @Bean
    public A1D1 a1DependencyBean() {
        A1D1 a1d1 = new A1D1(b1Dependency);
        retun a1d1;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
class ClassB {
    @Bean
    public B1D1 b1DependencyBean() {
        return new B1D1();
    }
}
```

By the time `a1DependencyBean` is created, the `b1DependecyBean` is not injected into the instance of `ClassA`. Reversing the order for the classes also did not make any difference.

My understanding was that spring will resolve the dependencies for a configuration class before creating the bean based on the `@Bean` annotation. Is there a different approach to be followed when using annotations for configurations?

Also when using spring boot, does the beans gets initialized based on the global application context and servlet context? If so what is the criteria which decides the context to which the beans are associated to?

---

The major functionality (Bean methods) for the corresponding real classes are as below.

ClassA

```
This class has most of the initializations that we do for the web application. 
It contains @Bean annotated methods which creates ServletRegistrationBeans, implementations of ApplicationContextAware interface, 
RequestMappingHandlerAdapter, Interceptors, MimeFileTypeMap, EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
```

ClassB

```
This class generates the beans required for customizing the views. It contains customized MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter bean, 
and org.springframework.web.servlet.View implementations for different content types.
```

The problem that we are seeing is that the View implementation bean (@Autowired property in ClassA) is not injected (@Bean method not yet invoked in ClassB) 
by the time the interceptor beans are generated from ClassA (using @Bean methods).

Is there a way to determine which context (root or Servlet Context) each beans get assigned to? 
And is it possible to override and customize the assigned context?

Comment: Your understanding is correct and the scenario that you've described should work. Indeed, I've just tried it with Spring Boot 1.1.10 and 1.2.1 and it worked as expected; an instance of A1D1 is created with a non-null instance of B1D1 injected into its constructor. Can you share some more details about the code that you're using to recreate the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have added more detailed explanation in my original post.